# How can I make Safari not use a cached version of a page?

Tags: safari

In Safari 13.1 on MacOS 10.15.4, I have a page cache that seemingly can't be cleared.

I'm working on a site, served at `localhost`. When I load the page, I can see in my server logs that Safari requests the page, but it ignores the response and displays an outdated version of the page.

If I close the web inspector, the current version of the page loads, as expected. If I re-open the web inspector, the cached version loads.

I've tried:

- Normal page refreshes
- Going into the `Network` tab of the web inspector and toggling the "Use the resource cache when loading resources" button
- Clicking the "reload" button in the inspector
- Pressing "option + command + r" as that button's tool tip suggests, which is supposed to "reload page ignoring cache"
- `Develop -> Empty Caches`
- Quitting Safari and opening it again

Nothing helps.

In the Network tab of inspector, the request for the main page shows "(inspector override)" in the "Transfer Size" column, which seems to confirm that it's using some kind of cache.

How can I get Safari not to use a cache for this page when the web inspector is open?

Answer (score 3):

### Get Rid of the "Local Override"

The message "(inspector override)" in the "Transfer Size" column of the web inspector's Network tab indicates that a [local override](https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/) is set.

Also, I hadn't noticed that the page's icon was inverted in the Network tab, as that page says.

**Without override**:
[image: without override]

**With overide**:
[image]

When a local override is set,

> [Web inspector will] intercept the network activity and replace it with a local override, allowing for quick local testing without having to modify anything on a server.
>
> When Web Inspector is open, network requests made by the inspected page that match the URL of a local override will instead use the the response content and MIME type, response status, and response headers from Web Inspector, rather than from the network or memory/disk cache.
>
> https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/

In my case, I did not know about this feature (which is actually pretty cool!) and apparently had created an override by accident.

To remove a local override, go into the Sources tab of the web inspector, find the "Local Overrides" section on the left, and either uncheck the local override for the page in question or right click it and select "Delete Local Override".